# Add custom data on Order view frontend page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento1.9.2.3

How to add my custom data or field under shipping method section in the frontend order view page without overriding template file(app\design\frontend\default\yourtheme\template\sales\order\info.phtml).
can i do it by using Event Observer(core_block_abstract_to_html_after) Please Help.[image]